# Fix bad referer URLs

Tags: url, http-status-code-404, external, bad-request

I recently notice bad URLs coming from external sites to my site.

I get a lots of 404 not found from sites that reference my site using a bad link like:

My site - http://www.example.com/mypage/CachedOnTuesdays

My link should be: http://www.example.com/mypage/

I know I cannot ask them to fix it. Is there a way for me to remove the last part of the URL to display the correct page?

Comment: The easiest solution I could think of is uses PHP. Is that an option? Next best choice would be JavaScript.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/CachedOnTuesdays$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```